# Rest Api error 400

Tags: rest-api, error, production

This Rest api Java code authenticate  to insert lead is working in my dev org
But when I try to do the same in production it throws **error 400**
Can anybody sort it out.

```
          static final String USERNAME     = "arshadsdeveloper@gmail.com.dev";
           static final String PASSWORD     = "************************";
           static final String LOGINURL     = "https://login.salesforce.com";
           static final String GRANTSERVICE = "/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password";
           static final String CLIENTID     = "************************";
           static final String CLIENTSECRET = "************************";
           private static String REST_ENDPOINT = "/services/data";
           private static String API_VERSION = "/v35.0";
           private static String baseUri;
           private static Header oauthHeader;
           private static Header prettyPrintHeader = new BasicHeader("X-PrettyPrint", "1");
           private static String leadId ;
           private static String leadFirstName;
           private static String leadLastName;
           private static String leadCompany;

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

       // Assemble the login request URL
       String loginURL = LOGINURL +
                         GRANTSERVICE +
                         "&client_id=" + CLIENTID +
                         "&client_secret=" + CLIENTSECRET +
                         "&username=" + USERNAME +
                         "&password=" + PASSWORD;

       // Login requests must be POSTs
       HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(loginURL);
       HttpResponse response = null;

       try {
           // Execute the login POST request
           response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
       } catch (ClientProtocolException cpException) {
           cpException.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException ioException) {
           ioException.printStackTrace();
       }

       // verify response is HTTP OK
       final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
       if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
           System.out.println("Error authenticating to Force.com: "+statusCode);
           // Error is in EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())
           return;
       }
```

this Rest api code authenticate  to insert lead is working in my dev org
But when I try to do the same in production it throws **error 400**
Can anybody sort it out.

Comment: Have you tried changing the API version to 34.0? Might be that your prod org isn't on 35 yet (I may be off base, I've lost track of where the releases are up to).

Comment: Yeah I tried that. but didn't got the success.

Comment: You need to URLEncode the components of the loginURL (CLIENTID etc). also look at the response body, it should have a error message in it that'll give you more clues.

Comment: (1) your username `arshadsdeveloper@gmail.com.dev` in Dev won't be the same in PROD - but assuming you thought of this, (2) Did you try using cURL  as an alternate testing path?

Comment: No I am using same url path. can you post alternate path.

Comment: response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(); This is returning 400

Comment: Your username in the code you posted is most likely not a valid username for login.salesforce.com

Comment: I am using some other credentials for production. this is my dev org username. its working fine. but when I replace them with production credentials It doesn't behave same.

Comment: Can you paste the whole error text you are getting? Error Code 400 could mean a lot of things.

Comment: Santanu can you see at the bottom response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(); This is returning 400. Thats it. Now how to populate more description.

Comment: Print the response object. It will have other details as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting instance name instead of `login.salesforce.com` write `instance.salesforce.com`. 
Generating Remote access in one go.

This resolved my issue.
Thanks Everyone for replying.
:)

Comment: Interesting! I thought the instance is needed once you are making calls with oAuth2 validated.